How in Craft 5 how do I query for related entries that are related from within a matrix field in a matrix field (nested matrix fields)?
In Craft 5 how do I query for related entries that are related from within a matrix field in a matrix field (now entryTypes) (nested matrix fields).
I want to show all related models for a product.
The setup is as follows;
The models is straight forward and are in  a section called cwtModels
The way these are associated in the products is a little more tricky, but I am hoping I can still find all models associated within a single product.
So I have a section is called products in this is a Matrix field called contentBuilderProducts and this has various entryTypes but the models are in an  EntryType called blockPerformance. This EntryType has a matrix filed called performanceData and within this are more entryTypes. Within this is a field called performanceCwtModelGroup and this has a field called cwtModels where the models are assigned.
I know the above sounds massively complicated but it is essentially a nested matrix within matrix and I want to show all the models selected within each product page.
I have tried the standard .relatedTo() but without any joy. I have also tried using targetElement and field but it is so deep I am not sure what to use...for example:
{% set modelQuery = craft.entries.section('cwtModels').relatedTo({
   targetElement: selectedProduct,
   field: 'contentBuilderProducts.blockPerformance.performanceData.performanceCwtModelGroup.cwtModels'
}) %}

